# ¿Cómo puedo esperar a que termine un proceso en ejecución para poder continuar con la ejecución de otro código en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

Tengo una pequeña pregunta, tengo una app que utiliza este fragmento de código:

```java
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Numero.getText().toString()));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Para poder realizar llamada desde mi aplicación, ¿qué pasa?, que necesito obtener la duración y el número marcado para continuar con el proceso y para obtenerlo necesito esperar que la llamada termine.

Me gustaría saber cómo podría hacer para esperar a que la llamada termine para continuar con el proceso y la ejecución del resto de código. He leído sobre `AsyncTask` y he probado hacerlo con lo que he investigado, pero no lo he logrado.

He intentado esto:

```
private void setCallIdel() {
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE://Esto se ejecuta al finalizar la llamada
                 //Aca va el bloque de codigo que se tiene que ejecutar al finalizar la llamada
            }
        }
    }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
```

Cuando ejecuto la app por primera vez, obtiene los datos y me lo guarda sin ningún problema, pero al intentar guardar nuevos datos este me lo guarda en la base de datos 2 veces, ósea 2 registro pero con los datos desordenado, y si intento guardar por 3ra vez este me guarda entonces 3 registro con los datos desordenado.

Para que guarde los datos correctamente tengo que cerrar la app completamente y volver abrir.

Intente reiniciar la actividad cada vez que se guardan los datos para reiniciar los valores de las variables pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Esta puede ser una posible solución [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15240210)

Comment: Ya lo arreglé @Excode

Comment: No estaría entendiendo bien a que te refieres con que se guarda varas veces, si pudieras adjuntar el código con lo que dices que se guarda, quizá podamos entender mejor la ptoblemática

Comment: Bien, pero necesitamos ver cómo haces para guardarlo porque puede que ahí este el problema

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar los permisos del Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Ahora viene la parte que quieres saber:

```
    //Super importante pedir permisos para poner leer
    final String[] NECESSARY_PERMISSIONS = new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG };

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(CallActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Si se concede permiso

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

        if(c.getCount() >= 1){
            while(c.moveToNext()){

                String num= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));// String del numero
                String name= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));// String del nombre
                String duration = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));// String de la duracion
                int type = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)));// String del tipo de llamada, entrante o saliente.

                textView_call.setText(name+" "+duration); //Seteo el nombre y la duracion de la llamada en un textview



            }
      }

    } else {

        //Pregunta por el permiso

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CallActivity.this,NECESSARY_PERMISSIONS, 123);
      }
   }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo @Osdward, ya obtengo esos datos, mi problema es: Que quiero enviar esos datos a mi DataBase y para obtenerlo tengo que esperar que la llamada finalice, entonce mi preguta es: Como puedo esperar que la llamada finalice para poder obtener los datos y proseguir con los bloques de codigos correspondiente

Comment: Bueno creo que tienes que dar mas código para ver que es lo que haces.